# Because project name requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.6, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dart

How to solve this problem. When I run flutter pub get this error will be shown. I have changed the environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.6" but this error is still the same. I tried running the flutter clean flutter upgrade but still can't solve this issue. What should I do?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I tested this package on my project. try this sdk: '>=2.19.5 <3.0.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do either downgrade flutter version or need to update animated_floatbutton plugin for latest flutter version.because this plugin version not supported for flutter version 2.12.0

Answer (score 0):

The package specified in the issue (animated_floatactionbuttons) should be upgraded to a version that is compatible with your current Dart SDK version.

The animated_floatactionbuttons version is not null safety enabled while your SDK version is null safety enabled.

Solution will be to upgrade the aimated_floatactionbuttons package version to a version that meet your current Dart SDK requirements. If there are no updated version of this package, then I think you need to find an alternative package to make use of.